.NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App project "az-AZ" culture not work
.NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App project I added "az-AZ" culture to Program.cs file but it does not work. But other languages work.
Program.cs
using BlazorApp1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("az-AZ");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("az-AZ");

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

BlazorApp1
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
      
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Hi @Khalig Heydarov, how is your other configuration for the localization? Here are the official document: how to set the culture.

@Rena Hi. I think all configs are ok. Because when I change to "tr-TR" it works.

Hi @Khalig Heydarov, have you tried other culture no only tr-TR and az-AZ? All the other culture can work fine? I think it better for you to share how do you configure the localization and how do you get the culture. By client side setting or from the headers or any other way.

@Rena Yes it works normally.

Hi @Khalig Heydarov, check this github issue that it seems to be by design. You can have a look at the link in last comment  and have a try to do customization.

I am sorry I just need to ask: Is this a WebAssembly or is this ServerSide? It looks like WebAss to me, but you have given both tags.

Also for others on this page
There also is a discussion about this issue, where we get more detail, specifically: Changing the culture DOES work and HAS impact, but there are problems with stuff like the .ToLower() method

I found answer from Microsoft and it works. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/104717
"az" is not included by default in WASM app internalization data, see: available cultures.
BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData works only for Blazor WASM app. It loads all cultures from the "available cultures" list mentioned above. An equivalent in WASM app is <WasmIcuDataFileName>icudt_custom.dat</WasmIcuDataFileName> doc.
If you want to add any culture that is not added to "available cultures" cultures list (e.g. "az-Latn-AZ"), you should follow custom ICU instruction and use your own version of icu file, populating WasmIcuDataFileName with its name.

See https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/csharp/get-installed-ui-culture-enumeration-of-culture-names.html
Specify whether the language script is Cyrillic or Latin:
az-Cyrl-AZ
vs.
az-Latn-AZ

Looks like these can be simplified to:
az-Cyrl   <-- Азәрбајҹан дили
vs.
az-Latn   <-- azərbaycan
I have not tested; I think these act the same as the above two choices.

Example usage:
new CultureInfo("az-Cyrl");

I used all of them but not worked.
